# Segfault when using dynamic loading with libssl.so

Tags: c, openssl, dynamic-linking

I am trying to dynamically load `libssl.so` using the code

```
typedef int (*SSL_library_init_t)(void);
typedef void (*SSL_load_error_strings_t)(void);

int main()
{
    SSL_library_init_t SSL_library_init;
    SSL_load_error_strings_t SSL_load_error_strings;

    ssl_library = dlopen("libssl.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!ssl_library) {
        printf("Failed to load libssl");
        return 1;
    }

    SSL_library_init = (SSL_library_init_t)dlsym(ssl_library, "SSL_library_init");
    SSL_load_error_strings = (SSL_load_error_strings_t)dlsym(ssl_library, "SSL_load_error_strings");

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

};
```

it loads and does not throw any errors until `SSL_library_init()` is executed, the compiled program throws a segfault without any other information

how i know that it is `SSL_library_init()`
I stepped through the code in `gdb`

I am running an ubuntu amd64 system and i did install libssl using `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

I am compiling using make

```
X64CC = gcc
ARMCC = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
IN =  main.c
OUT = app 
INC = -Wall -Wextra --static -s -Os 
IGN = -Wno-unused-but-set-variable

arm-build:
    $(ARMCC) $(IN) $(INC) $(IGN) -o $(OUT) 
x64-build:
    gcc $(IN) -Wall -ggdb3 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
```

I compiled the same code for arm based computer and it worked fine

Comment: You should check for `NULL` on _all_ your `dlsym` calls. And, _no_ need to cast the return value from it.

Comment: _Side note:_ Your pointers exactly match the names of the SSL functions they want to point to. They are function scoped in `main`. So, that's okay [for now]. But, if you ever want to split up the code in `main`, you'll need to make them file scope [possibly with `static`]. To future proof things, I'd use slightly different names (e.g.):  `SSL_library_init_t SSL_library_init;` --> `SSL_library_init_t my_SSL_library_init;` Also, I have to ask: What is the [good] reason for using dynamic linking in this situation?

Comment: I'd also not use types that end with `_t`.  Those [are reserved by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02): "Implementations may add symbols to the headers shown in the following table, provided the identifiers for those symbols either: ... 3. End in the string indicated as a reserved suffix. ... **ANY header** ... `_t`"

Answer (score 1):

Asides from the lack of checking of the return codes from dlsym, you're assuming the version of openssl is 1.0.

This is only going to be the case if you're running, for example, ubuntu xenial; which is out of support, or centos/redhat 7.

Neither of these functions are present in openssl 1.1 or newer. They've been replaced with the newer `OPENSSL_init_ssl` function. In fact if you look at the openssl/ssl.h file you will see a bunch of preprocessor macros:

```
ssl.h:#  define SSL_library_init() OPENSSL_init_ssl(0, NULL)
ssl.h:#  define SSL_load_error_strings() \
ssl.h-    OPENSSL_init_ssl(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_SSL_STRINGS \
ssl.h-                     | OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CRYPTO_STRINGS, NULL)
```

You *really* need to know what you're doing here attempting to manually use openssl in this manner. You would probably need multiple code-paths depending on the version of openssl you're loading.

Comment: the software i am writing only needs to support openssl 1.1

Comment: Very strange that the arm version works in in that case, if it's also openssl 1.1, then it _should_ have crashed in the same way. the openssl documentation mentions that both of those functions are deprecated: `The SSL_library_init() and OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms() functions were deprecated in OpenSSL 1.1.0 by OPENSSL_init_ssl()`, so you should use that function instead.